# How to pass dynamic multiple parameters in web.sitemap?

Tags: query-string, sitemap, breadcrumbs, url-parameters, web.sitemap

I have one page like (test.aspx) now i want to set its URL and Title in site map but the problem is that the same page (test.aspx) is calling from more then two place or links.Now i want to set Title and URL with multiple dynamic generated query string.But it is not allowing me to set multiple URL having dynamic parameters with different Titles.

Suppose, If test.aspx is calling from two places:

1. Home > Product > Test (Test.aspx)
2. Home > Price > Test Page (Test.aspx)

Now, Here The same page is calling from two places one is from Product and the other one is from Price. It should display as above in Breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same page but with different query parameters. If you have test.aspx that needs to be called from two different places, here's how you need to frame your sitemap.

```
<siteMapNode  url="~/Test.aspx?Parm=Product" title="Home-Product-Test.." ../>
<siteMapNode  url="~/Test.aspx?Parm=Price" title="Home-Price-Test.." ../>
```